# С помощью команды find найти файлы, которые никогда не модифицировались OC UNIX

Tags: linux, unix

Используя команду find, необходимо найти и вывести на экран содержимое всех файлов в поддереве каталогов, размер которых находится в каком-то произвольном диапазоне и которые никогда не модифицировались. C размерностью файла все понятно, но как прописать условие, что файлы никогда не модифицировались, подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: Любой файл обязательно модифицировался как минимум в момент своего создания. Какой смысл вы вкладываете в фразу «никогда не модифицировались»?

Comment: *как прописать условие, что файлы никогда не модифицировались* : если коротко, то — никак.

Answer (score 0):

Можно считать что файл не модифицировался, если время его создания равно времени модификации, тогда найти такие файлы и вывести их содержимое можно такой командой:

```
find . -type f -exec stat -c %n#%Y#%W {} \; | awk -F# '{if ($2 == $3) print $1}' | xargs cat
```

Что здесь происходит:

- запускается команда `stat -c %n#%Y#%W` для каждого файла, где: %Y - время последней модификации данных в секундах с начала Эпохи, %W - время создания файла в секундах с начала Эпохи; 0, если неизвестно.
- эти даты сравниваются здесь: `'{if ($2 == $3) print $1}'`. Если условие истинно выводится имя файла которое передаётся в первом пункте как `%n`
- имена всех найденных файлов поступают на вход `xargs`, который запускает команду вывода содержимого.

Comment: В *nix время создания файла не используется, соответственно %W будет всегда выводить 0 / (Для linux в качестве точки  отсчета я бы взял самый старый из файлов в /boot)

Comment: Прописал данную команду. Результат: find: paths must precede expression: awk
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]

Comment: @avp Может и не использоваться если так будет настроено.

Comment: @ОлегСтепанов Какая система? Нигде не ошиблись?

Comment: @avp, вообще говоря, со времён linux-4.11 и coreutils-8.31 btime должен корректно выводится для большинства родных ФС... но это, конечно, время создание инода и оно может изменятся ФС относительно произвольно... и в точности оно почти никогда не будет совпадать с mtime'ом...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, uname -a пишет `Linux avp-desktop 5.4.0-54-generic`, читаю man 2 stat и нигде не вижу **btime** (только как и раньше atime, mtime и ctime, только с наносекундами). Где спрятано btime?

Comment: @avp, `man 2 statx`

Comment: @Fat-Zer, спасибо. Чем все же хорош SO, так тем, что все время узнаешь что-то новенькое. / Кстати, у меня btime все же есть, debugfs видит его